# Create DLL From Existing Visual studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a c++ project developed in visual studio. The project which is currently .exe depends on external libs (xerces c++ and system C libraries). I now need to create a dll file (taking into account all the external libraries if possible).

1. Is there a way to convert the existing project into a dll (a tool) ?
2. If I need to create a dll project from the scratch (which is crazy cos the project is large :( ) what happens to the external libs - i.e. will a user need
   to configure those lib before using my dll?

Thanks guyz for your help

Answer (score 8):

You can change the `Configuration Type` in the `General` page of the project properties. Select `Dynamic Library (.dll)`. The library projects can be consumed as before.

If you need to keep the .EXE project you have to make copy, of course.

Comment: Sorry if my question is trivial, but how about improt/export functions, do we need to define it or MS VS will do that for  us as well?

Comment: The set of exported functions is always defined by the developer. Use a DEF file to list them or add appropriate function specs. There is no difference in importing functions from other DLLs, just use e.g. import libraries.